# Cassandra and Solr integration: Unable to execute query

Tags: solr, cassandra, integration

I'm trying to integrate cassandra and solr. 
I'm using solr -6.6.0 version, cassandra 3.10 version and java 8.

To my solrconfig.xml I added these lines

```
<lib dir="/home/bkoganti/solr-6.6.0/contrib/dataimporthandler/" regex="cassandra-jdbc-.*\.jar"/>
<lib dir="/home/bkoganti/solr-6.6.0/contrib/dataimporthandler/" regex="cassandra-all-.*\.jar"/>
<lib dir="/home/bkoganti/solr-6.6.0/contrib/dataimporthandler/" regex="cassandra-thrift-.*\.jar"/>
<lib dir="/home/bkoganti/solr-6.6.0/contrib/dataimporthandler/" regex="libthrift-.*\.jar"/>
<lib dir="/home/bkoganti/solr-6.6.0/contrib/dataimporthandler/" regex="cassandra-driver-core-*\.jar"/>
.
.
.
.
<requestHandler name="/dataimport" class="solr.DataImportHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="config">sample-data-config.xml</str>
    </lst>
</requestHandler>`
```

sample-data-config.xml

```
<dataConfig>
        <dataSource type="JdbcDataSource" driver="org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraDriver" url="jdbc:cassandra://127.0.0.1:9160/demo" autoCommit="true"/>
        <document name="content">
                <entity name="test" query="SELECT id,org,name,dep,place,sal from tutor" autoCommit="true">
                        <field column="id" name="id" />
                        <field column="org" name="org" />
                        <field column="name" name="name" />
                        <field column="dep" name="dep" />
                        <field column="place" name="place" />
                        <field column="sal" name="sal" />
                </entity>
        </document>
</dataConfig>
```

to managed schema I added these

```
<field name="org" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
<field name="dep" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
<field name="place" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
<field name="sal" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
```

On running solr and trying to import data from sample core, I'm unable to import. I keep getting this error.

[image]

[image]

I'm unable to figure out where I'm wrong could someone help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: click on the error line (red) and you will get an expanded stack trace. Or just look at solr.log.

Comment: @Persimmonium I did go through the stack trace. It says there is connection exception. I placed the driver in lib folder and gave the correct path, yet I'm getting the error.

Comment: would help to paste the error msg here no??

Comment: I edited the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last version of cassandra being supported by JDBC is 1.2.5. Later on, Datatstax developed the required drivers for Cassandra to get connected with JAVA applications. However, the datastax drivers cannot be used with solr as they have their own DSE search engine.

[This](https://github.com/zhicwu/cassandra-jdbc-driver) jdbc driver available is compatible with the latest versions of cassandra. Using this JDBC I could integrate.

And also [this](https://bitbucket.org/dbschema/cassandra-jdbc-driver) JDBC works.

Comment: How could you integrate with the library you mentioned? I always get the following error:

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.AbstractJdbcType

Comment: I gave the link for other JDBC, that as well works and can be used for development.

Comment: I'm using the DBSchema one. I can connect with SQL Squirel but when I add the same config into Solr 7.5, I get zero records. There are no errors in the log, and I see it reads 1 Request sent and 0 Received. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

that error means solr cannot reach cassandra via jdbc. First, you should check you can connect to cassandra from the Solr host, with java, by using some db tool like squirrelSQL or something similar.

Once you verified you can access it this way, move to solr. But you have something preventing it (a firewall, some wrong port, who knows...)

Comment: Thank you. The problem was with the version. Cassandra JDBC supports only for older versions of Cassandra. Datastax developed the required drivers for latest cassandra but particularly only for their packages.

Comment: Thank you, but the answer was not exact. Please edit the answer about the support of the versions.

Comment: [DataDirect's JDBC Driver for Cassandra](https://www.progress.com/jdbc/apache-cassandra) supports the latest versions of cassandra as well. I work with Progress DataDirect. Please take a look and let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanks I'm trying with it. I'm getting error like couldn't load driver. what is the jar file to be used. I installed using this link https://documentation.progress.com/output/DataDirect/jdbcinstallhelp/#page/installhelp/command-line-installation.html#

Answer (score 0):

use `nodetool enablethrift` for cassandra . your error is clearly saying unable to connect . connection refused .. after you enable thrift check it using `nodetool info` . hope this solves your problem .